# Spring Boot test - overriding bootstrap.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We are using bootstrap.properties in a Spring Boot app to configure Spring Cloud Config related properties.

We want to ignore these properties during the testing as we don't want to connect to config server for unit testing. So we are looking for a way to completely undo properties from main `bootstrap.properties` and provide a new one for testing or override selective properties.

We tried with creating `src/test/resources/bootstrap.properties`, `src/test/resources/bootstrap-test.properties` with `spring.cloud.config.enabled=false` property but it didn't work.

we tried to set as below before starting the TestClass

```
static {
    System.setProperty("spring.cloud.config.enabled", "false");
}
```

and it didn't work.

While Spring Boot documentation is pretty good about how application.properties works, I couldn't find even one reference to `bootstrap.properties`.

Any help is much appreciated on a reliable way to override `bootstrap.properties` during testing.

Answer (score 30):

If you are using the `@SpringBootTest` annotation you can override properties in the `bootstrap.properties` with the following:

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.cloud.config.enabled=false")
```

Otherwise, you can:

1. Add `@ActiveProfiles('test')` to your test class
2. Create a file named `bootstrap-test.properties`
3. Add the properties you want to overwrite e.g. `spring.cloud.config.enabled=false`

**Update:** If you want to disable spring cloud config for **all** tests, you can simply create a `bootstrap.properties` inside your `test/resources` folder with the following property:

`spring.cloud.config.enabled=false`

Comment: nice answer @Doug. Just specifying @ActiveProfiles('test') and providing an application-test.yml / application-test.properties will work.

Comment: no, it doesn't with SB 2.4.0+, as long you have bootstrap it will be downloaded first always

Answer (score 10):

(answering my own question here)

After lots of try and error found that by setting the spring profile to `test` it actually picks the `bootstrap-test.properties` and combines that with main `bootstrap.properties` file.

In this case, setting `spring.cloud.config.enabled=false` was still trying to bootstrap as in the main bootstrap it was set to `spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap = true` so we had to set this property to false in `bootstrap-test.properties` to inactive cloud server completely.

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Does not work for me. By default, `bootstrap-test.properties` is ignored. I had to add `@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:bootstrap-test.properties")` to my `@SpringBootTest` class. Using Spring Boot Starter 1.5.3.RELEASE.

Comment: I did the following:

*modified* build.gradle to specify the spring profile for unit test like this:
`test {
 systemProperties System.properties
 systemProperties.put("spring.profiles.active","unittest")
}`
*created* `bootstrap-unittest.yml` and placed it into `src/test/resources`.  It is configured with all of the `spring.cloud` enabled properties to false.

Comment: @user909481 `bootstrap-test.properties` will only be picked up automatically if your test has `@ActiveProfiles('test')`. If you need to disable it for all tests, please see my answer above

Comment: @toddcscar that works, but if you want to disable for all tests, you don't even need to set a profile if you don't want to. (see my answer above)

Answer (score 0):

For manual testing, I have added local application.yml and bootstrap.yml files to the root of my working directory. The application.yml contains a single line:

```
spring.cloud.bootstrap.location: file:.
```

This setting activates the local bootstrap.yml file in the working directory and disables the one on the classpath. The idea came from [Spring Boot 2 #466](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/466)